# No JNI_load found..Application closing and running in loop

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am getting this message which is not allowing my apps to run which contain some native C/C++ files, which I build using NDK. Apps is closing and opening again and crashing in a loop. I am getting below compilation warning after making some awk related changes in android.mk 
C:/android-ndk-r8/build/core/add-application.mk 128:Android NDK : Warning: APP-PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minsdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml

I have checked relevant threads associated with it, but couldn't find anything which can help me. Can anyone please help me, what I am missing here.

***Logcat Output:***

```
15:44:15.815: E/Trace(3026): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-28 15:44:16.007: D/dalvikvm(3026): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.raptorjni-2/libraptorq-test.so 0x40ce6428
05-28 15:44:16.035: D/dalvikvm(3026): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.raptorjni-2/libraptorq-test.so 0x40ce6428
05-28 15:44:16.035: D/dalvikvm(3026): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.raptorjni-2/libraptorq-test.so 0x40ce6428, skipping init
05-28 15:44:16.255: D/RaptorQ(3026): Entering the main function
```

Java main file snippet from where the C function is called :

```
   Log.d(TAG,"isteps Ecoded" + isteps);
        /* Call the JNI-ized version of DFRQEncPerfTest */
        String res = 
        resultRQEncPerfString(nSrcSymbols, symbolSize, loss, niter,
                      mode, 0, header);
```

**.C file function Snippet:**

```
jstring 
Java_com_example_raptorjni_RaptorJni_resultRQEncPerfString
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, 
   jint nSrcSymbols, jint symbolSize, jint lossrate, jint nLoop, 
   jint mode, jint nRepair, jint header)
{   

  Implementation ....
```

Comment: "No JNI_OnLoad found" Is an advisory notification, it is not an error (and certainly not a fatal one).  Please edit that out of your question and post logcat up through the actual restarting.  Also, the implementation of your native method would be good, as returning a jstring is something easy to attempt improperly.

Comment: 15:44:15.815: E/Trace(3026): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-28 15:44:16.007: D/dalvikvm(3026): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.example.raptorjni-2/libraptorq-test.so 0x40ce6428
05-28 15:44:16.035: D/dalvikvm(3026): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.raptorjni-2/libraptorq-test.so 0x40ce6428
05-28 15:44:16.035: D/dalvikvm(3026): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.example.raptorjni-2/libraptorq-test.so 0x40ce6428, skipping init
05-28 15:44:16.255: D/RaptorQ(3026): Entering the main function

Comment: No, there is definitely more to it than that.  You've not posted any of the activity startup.  Post a full cycle, form one activity startup, no jni onload, through to the next.  And make sure you have logcat run with no filtering.

Answer (score 3):

`JNI_Onload` is *optional* initialization function introduced since JNI 1.4 (more or less), that allows developers to do some init jobs while library is loaded (for example, register native methods to jvm).

So we really don't need javah or something stupid to implement native java methods in c/c++, just call `JNIEnv::registerNatives` inside `JNI_Onload` .

For this issue, I think something else was wrong.